# Have Modal that stays open need to close after saving

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Have modal that stays open after saving need to to close after clicking save changes

×Close
                    Catalog Request Form
                  
                  
                        
                        
                          
                            First Name
                            
                              
                            
                          
                          
                            Last Name
                            
                              
                            
                          
                          
                            Email *
                            
                              
                            
                          
                          
                            Phone
                            
                              
                            
                          
                          
                            Address

```
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control cr_city" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="City">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control cr_state" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="State">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Zip Code</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control cr_zipcode" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Zip Cope">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Truck Make (Peterbilt, Kenworth, Etc.)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control cr_truck" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Truck Make (Peterbilt, Kenworth, Etc.)">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cr_clear">Clear</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cr_submit">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This is a javascript problem, not a php one and it shouldn't require anything fancy if you're using modal correctly, but because you're apparently not...why not throw in some javascript that just closes the box on submit/x'd.

Comment: I'm retagging this as it looks like Twitter's Bootstrap. If that's accurate, the docs tell you exactly how to do this.

Comment: On your submit button JS handler, simply call the close routine.  `$('#YOURmodalIDHERE').modal('toggle');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call either `$('#YourModalID').modal('hide')` or `$('#YourModalID').modal('toggle')` at the end of your button click handler in your JavaScript.

[**See the documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) on Bootstrap modal methods and events for further details on how to effectively use modals.